# How rotate TomCat 6 logs on Windows every night

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat, log-files

Our Tomcat 6 is running on a Windows Server 2003 server producing some logs on `Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\logs` folder.

Only `catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log` rotates every night.

Files `Admin`, `Host-Manager`, `Jakarta`, `LocalHost`, `Manager`, `stderr` and `stdout` do not rotate and are dated at the last server restart date. These files are most empty and always locked.

How can I set Tomcat to rotate all these logs every night (if possible without server/service restart)?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Related: SO: [*How to rotate tomcat logs in Windows? What is the best method?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079915/how-to-rotate-tomcat-logs-in-windows-what-is-the-best-method/)

Answer (score 1):

In Linux (and FreeBSD) we have `logrotate`. On Windows, I think you can compile its source against Cygwin.

logrotate source: https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/

Cygwin installer: http://www.cygwin.com

Tip for compiling logrotate on Cygwin: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-11/msg00856.html

Comment: Installing cygwin may be a solution for someone, but after some research I forund out that there is a tool called rotatelogs which comes out-of-the-box with Apache. It can be configured for log rotation editing httpd.conf. An example would be: 

#daily rotation 
CustomLog "| D:\Progra~1\Apache~1\Apache\bin\rotatelogs.exe 
logs\access%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.log 86400 -300" common

Some blogs advertise that rotatelogs is quite buggy, so after some time you can find many instances of rotatelogs in your process list. At the moment it is not clear to me if there is a solution for this issue.